# Jenkins plugin development - add dependency and using RunMap class AbstractProject._getRuns()

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins plugin development and I'm trying to start by editing an existing plugin to add some more features for my need.

I'm changing the [Audit2DB](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin) plugin and I want when this plugin save a Build_Detail data it will store the child jobs, the jobs this current build has been triggered via parameterized plugin or via post build task. There are 2 types of child projects:

1.
Triggered during build step via parameterized plugin, we can get these projects (unblocked call) or builds (blocked call) by:

```
`def infoActions = runBuild.getActions(hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildInfoExporterAction)
infoActions.each { action ->
  def triggeredProjects = action.getTriggeredProjects()
  if (triggeredProjects != null) {
    triggeredProjects.each {
      println it.getDisplayName()
    }
  }
  def triggeredBuilds = action.getTriggeredBuilds()
  if (triggeredBuilds != null) {
    triggeredBuilds.each {
    println it
    }
  }
}`
```

I can run these code in Jenkins but when I implement it within the plugin, I have to declare the hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildInfoExporterAction class, which is belong to Parameterized plugin. I tried to add dependency to this plugin in the pom.xml like below [from](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dependencies+among+plugins?showChildren=true#children):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>parameterized-trigger</artifactId>
  <version>2.31</version>
</dependency>'
```

However, when I build the plugin, it caused error on the unitTest:

```
org.jenkins.plugins.audit2db.test.integration.WhenAccessingJobHistoryReport)  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< ERROR!java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/model/RunAction2
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.jvnet.hudson.annotation_indexer.Index$2$1.fetch(Index.java:101)
at org.jvnet.hudson.annotation_indexer.Index$2$1.hasNext(Index.java:71)
at org.jvnet.hudson.annotation_indexer.FilterIterator.fetch(FilterIterator.java:23)
at org.jvnet.hudson.annotation_indexer.FilterIterator.hasNext(FilterIterator.java:42)
at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.discoverTasks(InitializerFinder.java:70)
at hudson.init.InitializerFinder.discoverTasks(InitializerFinder.java:55)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskBuilder$2.discoverTasks(TaskBuilder.java:40)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.<init>(Reactor.java:128)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.<init>(Reactor.java:133)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.<init>(Jenkins.java:821)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:821)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:761)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.newHudson(HudsonTestCase.java:441)
at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.setUp(HudsonTestCase.java:300)
at org.jenkins.plugins.audit2db.test.integration.WhenAccessingReportPages.setUp(WhenAccessingReportPages.java:49)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
at org.jvnet.hudson.test.HudsonTestCase.runBare(HudsonTestCase.java:285)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.model.RunAction2
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 64 more
```

I tried to copy the parameterizedtrigger.jar into the lib/WEB-INF folder but no luck. Seems the error from but I have no idea to fix:

```
public abstract class WhenAccessingReportPages extends HudsonTestCase {
...
@Before
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
super.setUp();
jenkins.setSecurityRealm(getSecurityRealm());
jenkins.setAuthorizationStrategy(getAuthStrategy());
}
```

2.
Trigger at post build (downstream projects)

```
def childs = project.getDownstreamProjects()
for (Iterator<AbstractProject> iterator = childs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  def childBuildsMap = iterator.next()._getRuns()
  for (child in childBuildsMap) {
    AbstractBuild childBuild = child
    println childBuild.toString()
  }
}
```

Again, when put these code into the plugin, we have to cash into explicit type, I'm having trouble when casting the AbstractProject._getRuns() that return a RunMap but I can't use the iterator() to scan through the list. I'm too bad in java code so I'm in trouble with those stuffs a lot.

It would be really great to hear from your help.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the plugin compile and test in your setup before you make any changes?

Comment: It can be compiled and tested before my changes, even with a simple change (change the value to save), I still can test with the plugin